# How to get first occurence of items after a certain column on a list in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose have a longitudinal data consist of individuals date and event, which is written as 3 dates here, but actually can vary for every individual:

| id | time1 | time2 | time3 | event1 | event2 | event3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2011-04-22 | [] | 2016-06-07 | [apple, orange] | [] | [orange, grape] |
| b | 2010-07-15 | 2014-07-12 | 2015-05-10 | [apple] | [apple, orange] | [apple, orange, grape] |

I want to get the first event after a certain time, for example, take time1 as the initial date, so I need to get the event after time1, which could be time 2 or time 3,

so I have done:

```
def substracttest(i):
    if (i>2):
        df['new_event'+str(i)]=df['event'+str(i)].apply(lambda x: [k for k in x if k not in substracttest(i-1)]).values
        return(df['new_event'+str(i)])
    else:
        df['new_event'+str(i)]=df['event'+str(i)].apply(lambda x: [k for k in x if k not in df['event'+str(i-1)]]).values
        return(df['new_event'+str(i)])
    

for j in range(2,4):
    substracttest(j)
```

to get the new event after each point in time, but if the time is empty, which means there's no event, I can't get the new events properly,

The output is:

```
new_event1         new_event2
[]                 [orange, grape]
[apple, orange]    [apple, orange, grape]
```

the expected output is

```
new_event1  new_event2
[]          [grape]
[orange]    [grape]
```

It's my first time handling time-related date, so I'm not really familiar with it yet,
And if there is any possible different approach to this, it will be appreciated.

edit:
I just tried things again and it works:

```
def substracttest(i):
    if (i>2):
        df['new_event'+str(i)]=df.apply(lambda row : np.setdiff1d(row['event'+str(i)],row['new_event'+str(i-1)]), axis=1)
        for j in range(1,i):
            df['new_event'+str(i)]=df.apply(lambda row : np.setdiff1d(row['new_event'+str(i)],row['event'+str(j)]), axis=1)
        return(df)
    else:
        df['new_event'+str(i)]=df.apply(lambda row : np.setdiff1d(row['event'+str(i)],row['event'+str(i-1)]), axis=1)
        return(df)
    

for j in range(2,4):
    substracttest(j)
```

Comment: Hello, if it works, please add an answer with your solution and describe it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a bit more, and it actually works,
so first of all I think the problem is on the apply on dataframe, I should have used the axis = 1, which I use on the answer

I am also using `numpy.setdiff1d` instead of the `k for k in x if k not in df['event'+str(i-1)]`, but I'm not really sure if it's any different.

```
def substracttest(i):
    if (i>2):
        df['new_event'+str(i)]=df.apply(lambda row : np.setdiff1d(row['event'+str(i)],row['new_event'+str(i-1)]), axis=1)
        for j in range(1,i):
            df['new_event'+str(i)]=df.apply(lambda row : np.setdiff1d(row['new_event'+str(i)],row['event'+str(j)]), axis=1)
        return(df)
    else:
        df['new_event'+str(i)]=df.apply(lambda row : np.setdiff1d(row['event'+str(i)],row['event'+str(i-1)]), axis=1)
        return(df)


for j in range(2,4):
    substracttest(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following in your function:

```
def substracttest(i):
    if df[f"time{i}"].empty:
        return []
    elif (i > 2): ........... (Continue with the rest of code)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have tried it but the results are still the same, still not the expected output